With the keybord module gone from python, are there any build in replacment modules in the latest version that can tell when certain keys are inputed?
It has be something from the built in library, it's for a school project so it can't be something else I have to download.
I'm trying to make something where events only happen when a certain key is pressed, but because
import keyboard doesn't exist, it can't work.
sorry if the question doesn't fit this site, this is my first time using it.

you might check out Terminal control functions
